# Is there a way in React.js to run a side effect after `useState` when the value of the state doesn't change in functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One thing I've recently been confused about is what the best way to run effects after a `useState` call, when the `useState` doesn't necessarily change the previous state value. For example, say I have a submit function in a form. Also say I have a state called `randomNumber`, and say in that submit function I call `setRandomNumber` and set the random number state to a random number from 1-2. Now say that for some reason every time the `randomNumber` is set, regardless of whether its value changes or not, we want to update the number in some database and navigate to a different page. If I use a `useEffect(() => {updateDatabase(); }, [randomNumber])`, the problem is that this will update the database even when the functional component first renders, which I do not want. Also, if the `randomNumber` doesn't change because we pick the same random number twice, we won't update the database after the second `setRandomNumber` call and we won't navigate to a different page which I don't want.

What would be the best way to 'await' a `useState` call. I read some articles saying we should potentially use `flushSync`, but I tried this and it doesn't seem to be working and it seems like this is a very unstable solution as of now.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different requests here.

1. How to skip a `useEffect` on the first render. For this you could employ [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) as this does not trigger a re-render

```
const Comp = () => {
 const firstRender = useRef(true);

 useEffect(() => {
   if (firstRender.current) {
    firstRender.current = false;
    return
   } else {
    // do your stuff
   }
 }, [randomNumber])
}
```

2. How to trigger `useEffect` even if you get the same number. Probably the simplest way would be to wrap your number inside an object and always generate a new object when generating a new number. This way you'll get a new ref all the time and the `useEffect` will always trigger. If you already have an object you could create a copy using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Something like this:

```
const Comp = () => {
 const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState({number: 0})

 useEffect(() => {
   console.log(randomNumber.number)
 }, [randomNumber])

 // generate a new random number and set it like this 
 setRandomNumber({number: Math.random() + 1))
}
```